# How to configure AAA server and hostapd to support Hotspot 2.0 / Passpoint?

Tags: wireless-networking, openwrt, hotspot, 802.11

I am trying to setup an independent Hotspot 2.0 network. I am using TP-Link Archer C7 v2 routers as accesspoint.

I built and flashed Openwrt 15.05 on router. Built hostapd from source with HS20 and interworking options available. I am able to see that beacon frames has HS20 and interworking capabilities.

How can I authenticate clients connected to AP? Do I need to run some kind of server running. What configuration I need to do on AP and server side?

Comment: 802.11u and Passpoint is a complex technology that should only be attempted by someone who is knowledgeable about not only wifi architectures, but access control mechanisms as well. While I'd love to help you, this question is far too broad.

Comment: @ToddJCrane Do you have maybe experience with configuring Cisco WLC for Passpoint? Which configuration settings correlates with the Passpoint profile data on the following link https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-passpoint#example_eap_ttls? Is it that I can configure any domain and realm name as long as they are stated in the Passpoint profile? I have succesfully installed the profile on the phone but it won't associate with the AP.